# Parse a string and get certain values

Tags: android, string, design-patterns

I have a string like this:

> _id:2 thread_id:189 **address:0292** m_size:null person:0 date:1372494272447 date_sent:0 protocol:0 read:1 status:-1 type:1 reply_path_present:0 subject:null **body:Ok. Reply message.**  service_center:051108 locked:0 sim_id:0 error_code:0 seen:1 _id:1 thread_id:189 **address:292** m_size:null person:0 date:1372493695831 date_sent:0 protocol:null read:1 status:-1 type:2 reply_path_present:null subject:null **body:Test message** service_center:null locked:0 sim_id:0 error_code:0 seen:0

I want to retrieve only parts of this string, for example the **address:0292** and the **body:xyz** from the entire string. I want all instances of these two from a very large String (above is just a sample). Let's assume its more than 20000 characters.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use StringTokenizer.  Something on the order of 20K characters isn't that big, still under 100K.  Even tokenizing it will still be under 1/4 meg of memory.

Comment: Sample code pliss :p I was thinking of using split and then searching the arrays but that doesn't sound like the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like every `address` is followed by `m_size`, so use the `string.split()` function, to split over the keyword `address` then select the `string.substring()` (from each string in the resulting array) until reaching the keyword `m_size`. And repeat the entire thing for the keywords `body` and `service_center`. I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it doesn't seem pretty. But it works :)

```
String[] splitString = string.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
if (splitString[i].startsWith("body") || splitString[i].startsWith("address"))
    Log.i(TAG, "Found: " + splitString[i]);
    // Do whatever you need to do
}
```